# Fetch data via ajax+webmethod or via traditional codebehind?

Tags: asp.net

I'm going to display a product detail from a database. But I can't decide whether to use an $.ajax post to a WebMethod that returns a JSON string, or a traditional Page.Load with sqldatareader in codebehind.

I know how to do both, coding is not the issue. I'm wondering what would be faster and more secure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what kind of data you are showing on the page. (more of howmuch data)

Lets say if you are showing a fixed amount of data like, summary, product detail then its better to fetch data from server side and bind in label in Page Load event.

But if you are about to display the list of item (which may vary depending on the user input) for example product list, order list, employee list. in that case it is good to fetch the rows using ajax. reason is to display the fixed number of rows on the page (lets say 10) and there should be a pagination to jump to the next/pre page. now when user click next or previous it should not post back the page and should get the rows using ajax.

Comment: Makes sense, edited my question to be more specific.

Comment: @JohnMcFiddly Ok. in case of product detail its fine to load from backend.

Answer (score 1):

Each method has its advantages and disadvantages.

### AJAX advantages and disadvantages

**Advantages:**

- Forces you to separate the concerns in the code a bit more, you will have the data gathering and the data display in different places
- The code will be more testable due to this additional modularity

**Disadvantages:**

- Slower due to the additional HTTP request
- Harder to deal with the back button and with bookmarking
- Search engine optimization will be harder due to data not being right in the html